# Issue with a mouse filter driver

Tags: c++, c, device-driver, drivers

I'm trying to implement a mouse filter driver by attaching "\Device\PointerClass0". Attaching the device to the stack using IoAttachDevice is successful.

The dispatch routine for IRP_MJ_READ sets a completion routine and then passes the IRP to lower drivers.

```
IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);
IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp,CompletionRoutine,DeviceObject,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE);
return IoCallDriver(TopMostDriver,Irp);
```

And then when the completion routine is called , it inverts Y axe :

```
NTSTATUS CompletionRoutine(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,PIRP Irp,PVOID Context){
PMOUSE_INPUT_DATA MouseData;
if(Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS){
    MouseData = (PMOUSE_INPUT_DATA)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    MouseData->LastY *= -1;
}
if(Irp->PendingReturned){
    IoMarkIrpPending(Irp);
}
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

The default dispatch routine for other Major Functions just passes the IRP to lower drivers.

The problem is when loading my driver , the default dispatch routine is being called 1 time only after attaching the driver, it doesn't get called after that nor the dispatch routine for IRP_MJ_READ.I checked using DeviceTree that my device is attached , the dispatch routine wouldn't be called if it isn't anyway.

EDIT : I actually found this statement at osronline :

```
the mouse input stacks are pnp and there is no way for you to put yourself 
into the stack after it has started running (you could install yourself as a filter and then restart the stack)
```

How can I actually restart a driver stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can inject yourself without restarting the device, but it's quite an unpleasant to do so.  You can find a driver that's in the device's stack, then copy all (or some) of its **MajorFunction** IRP-handlers to an array that you have, then replace all (or some) of those handlers with your own, being sure to "transparently" pass on the IRP to the handlers that you've "middle-manned."  That means you wouldn't have your own **IO_STACK_LOCATION** to work with, however.  This strategy is pretty nasty, so I wouldn't recommend it unless you have to.  (Read as "never do this.")

Better is to install your filter driver the way filter drivers are usually installed, then restart the device.  You can use user-mode PnP device-management functions to accomplish this, from some kind of installer utility you'd write, or simply document the installation process for users and let them do it.